# Oracle PL/SQL: Retrieve list of permissioned procedures for account

Tags: oracle, plsql, permissions

I've researched here and elsewhere but haven't found an answer for the following.

I'd like to get a list of all procedures available to my application's Oracle account (AFAIK they're part of one package), and have tried the following command in sqlplus:

```
 SELECT * from user_procedures;
```

However this only returns one row/procedure, when in fact the app has probably 20+ procedures it calls (successfully) on a regular basis. I can just look through the source code and extract all the stored procedure names, but I'd like to use the above and see it working, and as a basis for further examination of the db to assist in debugging (instead of always needing to run the app or write test client code, for example).

Does the above statement only return procedures my account owns explicitly, or should it show anything the account has access to? [I'm not very familiar with Oracle's specific features.]

I've tried other variations; for example, referencing 'dba_procedures' results in a 'table or view does not exist error.'

Are all of these symptoms the result of limited permissions on my app's Oracle account (which I'm using to connect via sqlplus)?

[Background: Dysfunctional environment--direct access to the DBMS and its external owners is extremely limited, so I'd like to be able to increase my understanding of the db design and get the information I need without assistance.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see which stand-alone procedure you can execute with this:

```
select ao.object_type, ao.owner ||'.'|| ao.object_name
from all_objects ao, user_tab_privs utp
where ao.object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
and utp.owner = ao.owner
and utp.table_name = ao.object_name
and utp.privilege = 'EXECUTE';
```

But if they are in a package you can't directly see the procedure names, AFAIK, but you can see which package you can execute with this:

```
select ao.object_type, ao.owner ||'.'|| ao.object_name
from all_objects ao, user_tab_privs utp
where ao.object_type = 'PACKAGE'
and utp.owner = ao.owner
and utp.table_name = ao.object_name
and utp.privilege = 'EXECUTE';
```

And then you can desc[ribe] the package to see the individual procedures and functions within it. I guess that is probably held somewhere in the data dictionary but don't knwo where off-hand...

Comment: Alex: Thanks, both work and the situation is as you've described. I ran 'desc' on the relevant package, spool'd the output to file and got exactly what I was looking for: a list of associated stored procs and their parameters. 'desc (package_name)' was the key.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Alex's answer is incomplete; for example, any procedures you've inherited the execute privilege wouldn't be included.  

Unless one has the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY privilege (and even not then, I suspect), 

SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME
  FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('PACKAGE', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')

The only grant I can think of that might apply to any of those object types are EXECUTE; SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and REFERENCES don't make sense.

Comment: `ALL_OBJECTS` will include anything you can see; you may be able to desc packages you can't if you don't have `EXECUTE`, though I'm not sure exactly when that can happen. You're right though, it isn't seeing privs granted through roles (including `PUBLIC`); you can get those from all_tab_privs instead:
    select ao.object_type, ao.owner ||'.'|| ao.object_name
    from all_objects ao, all_tab_privs atp
    where ao.object_type in ('PACKAGE', PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')
    and atp.schema_name = ao.owner
    and atp.table_name = ao.object_name
    and atp.privilege = 'EXECUTE';

Answer (score 1):

`user_procedures` is a system view that holds all the procedures owned by certain schema (user). Not the ones that the schema (user) is granted to execute.

You can try `DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL` stored procedure. You might find something useful there. But I don't know what kind of privileges you need to run it within your application.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Pablo: Thanks for the response. I ended up calling desc(ribe) on the package and got the output I was looking for. [Which is probably obvious to any of you guys familiar with Oracle!]

Answer (score 1):

If the procedures are part of a package (i.e. you're calling them by PACKNAME.PROCNAME, then you have an all-or-nothing grant on the package, not individual procedures within the package.

Comment: You're right, that's how the procedures are being called. I basically just want to ask Oracle: "What can this account do?"

Is there any way to do that, or do I just know that I have permission to do whatever is contained within that package?

[And again, this is because our support from the owning company is extremely limited. I want to help us help ourselves.]

Comment: dpbradley: Thanks for the help--I got things working as described above, but you confirmed what I was wondering about packages and permissions.